# Excel Macro to fetch random data from column A

Tags: vba, excel, visual-studio-macros

I have a list of data in column A and the same has repeated data too. I have to create a macro to get 10% of that data. I tried with Rand() and few other functions but no success. Please any help.

**Column A**

> Brick John
>
> Brick Matt
>
> Brick Ted
>
> Goal John
>
> Goal Matt
>
> Goal Ted
>
> Goal Ted
>
> Tiger Ted
>
> Tiger John
>
> Tiger Matt
>
> Tiger Matt
>
> Code Ted
>
> Code Matt
>
> Code Matt
>
> Code Ted
>
> Code John

Now from the above list I have to get random sample of 10% it is ok if I get duplicates to
but I have to get from all brick, tiger, code and goal.

Please help

Comment: Please add the code you have written to your question so we can help figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will sample and place the samples in column **B**

```
Public Sub scramble(InOut() As String)
Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long, Hi As Long
Dim Temp

ReDim Helper(LBound(InOut) To UBound(InOut)) As Double
Randomize
Low = LBound(Helper)
Hi = UBound(Helper)
For I = Low To Hi
    Helper(I) = Rnd()
Next

J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
Do While J > 0
    For I = Low To Hi - J
      If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
        Temp = Helper(I)
        Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
        Helper(I + J) = Temp
        Temp = InOut(I)
        InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
        InOut(I + J) = Temp
      End If
    Next I
    For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
      If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
        Temp = Helper(I)
        Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
        Helper(I + J) = Temp
        Temp = InOut(I)
        InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
        InOut(I + J) = Temp
      End If
    Next I
    J = J \ 2
Loop
End Sub


Sub samples()
Dim N As Long, N2 As Long, s() As String
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
N2 = N / 10
ReDim s(1 To N)

For I = 1 To N
  s(I) = Cells(I, 1).Value
Next I

Call scramble(s)

For I = 1 To N2
  Cells(I, 2).Value = s(I)
Next I
End Sub
```